# Logitech K120 keyboard detected but driver not found in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, logitech-keyboard

I have a [Logitech K120 keyboard](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/6692?osid=14&crid=404&bit=64) which is detected in device manager. But the driver is not found.

When I try to update the driver, it says `windows could not find driver software for your device`.

I have tried various driver packages like driver detective, but with unsuccessful result.
When I plug the keyboard into my Linux machine, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I just want to add this for others who are trying to help: [*"This product does not ship with software. It uses the native USB drivers already present in your operating system."*](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support/6692?osid=14&crid=404&bit=64)

Comment: Come on guys, the real problem isn't a missing driver. The system PnP driver should work fine, but he's not. Stay on that problem

Comment: @ayush, can you clarify if the keyboard doesn't work in Windows 7 or it's just the missing driver that annoys you (but no actual impact on the usage)

Answer (score 2):

I recently got a K120 Logitech keyboard and had the same exact issue.

The problem was that `usb.inf` was missing from the `C:\Windows\Inf Folder`.

Anyone who has this problem you may want to use your windows CD or a backup file if you have one of usb.inf and put it into your `windows\inf` directory.

Comment: I just ran into this issue with my K120, it says 'unknow device' in the device manager, windows 7. The usb.inf file is there. not sure what else I could try. (the keyboard is not working btw).

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for special driver for this keyboard [(source)](http://logitech-en-amr.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/22980/section/troubleshoot/crid/404/lt_product_id/6692/tabs/1,3,2,4,5/cl/us,en).

> Most Logitech products will work with no additional software or drivers needed. If no software is shown for your operating system on your PC or Mac, then software is not available for your product.

[image: k120-no drivers needed]

This particular keyboard should work fine with the default drivers which are included in the operating system.

Comment: I have not voted yet, but you should include the solution here as well

Comment: @AthomSfere, He asked for the driver. There's no driver. For me it sounds like he just got frustrated because he's go the "no driver found" window. Read carefully, he didn't say that the KB doesn't work (correct me if I'm wrong, seriously. I'm just saying. Not trying to be overwise here or anything)

Comment: He did not say it, but verifying it has *a* driver is trivial and would make this a good answer. Likewise showing how to force the selection of a generic Windows driver would make this answer a homerun for those in the future who might have the same issue. Also, when he states `When I plug the keyboard into my Linux machine, it works perfectly fine.` it makes me think it is not working...

Comment: I thought that too, but until he clarifies this I won't try to solve a problem that might not exist :)